# How long should I set the expire time for signed url?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I decided to use cloud storage signed url. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

How long should I set the expired time, for uploading and downloading? Some docs say should set the expired time as short as possible. 5 mins, 10 mins or 1 hour?

Is there any theoretical basis?

Comment: This depends entirely on the requirements of your application.  Without knowing that, there can be no recommendations, and it's just a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use X-Goog-Expires to specify the  [length of time the signed URL remained valid, measured in seconds](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#examples). As Doug said, the specific timeframe is dependent on your application and individual needs so you can modify the parameters over time to better suit your needs.